# Object literal creation in javascript object constructor using this

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, this, object-literal

I have an object constructor and I am trying to declare two object literals which I set and compare in a couple of functions. If the properties are different in the object literals after some procedure then I do some calculations and output the result.

```js
function myObject() {
    this.literal = {};
    this.literalCopy = {};
  
    this.setProperties = function() {
        this.literal.left = something;
     this.literal.offset = offsetLeft;
  this.literal.viewed = 5;
  this.literal.img = img_size;
  this.literalCopy = this.clone(this.literal); 
    }
    
    this.compareMethod = function() {
       for (prop in this.literalCopy) {
   if (!this.literalCopy.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  continue;
   }
   if(prop == 'img' && this.literalCopy[prop] != this.literal.img) {...} 
   if(prop == 'viewed' && this.literalCopy[prop] != this.literal.viewed) {...}  
      }  
    }
}
```

The comparison works fine for one object instance but not for more than one. The last instance always gets the correct comparison, the previous ones do nothing or are ignored. 
My question is: can I use an object literal the way I am using `this.literal = {}` in the constructor as I am pretty sure that the functions I am using them in are sound. I need to declare them using `this` as the object literals need to be available in the prototypes of `myObject`. If I am being naive in my coding could you suggest an alternative method.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you defined `this.clone` yourself or is it from a 3rd party library? How are you creating instances? Can you please give an example where it only compares on the last instance.

Comment: @puqeko I actually solved this after a while. The object literals and the methods of the object worked. I am creating instances of the object in a for loop into an array depending on the number of particular elements there are. The problem I had was that inside a window resize function I had a set timeout function which when cleared (after resizing) called the comparing function; only the last object instance was being returned. I took the call to the compareMethod out of the timeout and it worked, both instances being returned.